# How do I make WebDev clean up its tooltray "tracks"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-vista, webdev.webserver

After I've shut down a VS 2008 web project, well, a lot of times, I see many instances of the WebDev icon in the "tooltray" / system notification area:

[image: tooltray with webdev tracks]

These are no longer active instances; they were shut down by VS.

When I mouse over any of these, Windows Vista "conveniently" collapses the tray for me. This makes life miserable if the app I want is in between any of them (e.g., Outlook in the image above), and even worse if I actually want to right click on the "active" WebDev.

Any idea how I can get VS, WebDev, or Windows to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility on CodeProject that does this: TrayIconBuster 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/TrayIconBuster.aspx

It runs every x minutes and removes all phantom icons...

Not the perfect solution, because I think this should be built in to Windows...

Comment: +1 since it actually is a solution. Would like something better, but I'm starting to wonder if "something better" even exists.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and don't have this problem (maybe that's another solution), but most of the times VS closes normally, and then the icons go away automatically